# Symfony и Doctrine. Как в выборке связать 2 разные дочерние сущности одного класса?

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2

Добрый день.
У меня есть базовая сущность - **Place** и 2 ее дочерние - **InPlace** и **OutPlace**

Соответственно **InPlace** и **OutPlace** наследуются от **Place**.

Есть также класс геообъекта - **Geo**

```
class Geo{

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Base\Place", inversedBy="geo")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="place_id", referencedColumnName="geo_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
   */
  protected $place;

}
```

Как вы видите, в нем могут быть как **InPlace** так и **OutPlace**, и именно поэтому я привязываю с помощью базового класса **Place**

Собственно вопрос - делаю я выборку из БД, например, так (репозиторий **Geo**)

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('geo');
$qb
  ->select('geo')
  ->leftJoin('geo.place', 'place')
  // поля photo есть только в дочерних классах. В Place их нет
  ->leftJoin('place.photo', 'photo')
;
```

и получаю соответсвующую ошибку о том, что в классе **Place** нет поля *photo* (оно и правильно, ведь *photo* только в дочерних классах).

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при выборке подцеплялся не базовый класс, а дочерний класс, который привязан к данному **Geo**?

Копал в сторону *resolve_target_entity*, но там привязка идет одного класса к одному

Comment: Может быть дело в архитектуре? Ведь если посудить, в вашей сущности Geo свойство $place имеет тип Place, и даже если вы туда засетите объект типа InPlace или OutPlace, как вы будете пользоваться методом Geo::getPlace()? который будет возвращать тип Place? Неужели вы собрались пользоваться конструкцией instanceof? Т.е. вы все равно не сможете получить доступ к фотографиям, даже если они будут установлены в объекте In/OutPlace (в случае если вы действуете "честно" и не прибегаете постоянно к instanceof)

Comment: Думаю, вам нужно воспользоваться дискриминаторами. Пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453036/doctrine-entities-implementing-interface-in-order-to-typehint. Ну и доктриновская дока http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html